# Fixing the width of the first table column with css

Tags: css

I need to add some css code to a survey tool that I am using that can fix my tables the way I want. I need to set the width of the first column in a table to a fixed length in px. How do I do that? How do I point to the first column in the table in a generic way (i.e. without naming it) to set the width?

I have tried using tr and th but with no success.

Comment: Get ready to use some javascript my friend.

Comment: I don't Think I can use Javascript in this tool but I will investigate. How would the code for fixing the first column look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr td:first-child{
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: I have used first-child but is not working. I have tried on both IE and Firefox with no success. Any idea why?

Comment: Is there Another way of doing it without using :first-child?